# Controller unable to download Wordpress JSON data

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I can't seem to get my Wordpress JSON to work.  I'm brand new to the AngularJS and Ionic worlds, so I've been reading and watching tutorials.

This is the relevant part of my `app.js` file:

```
(function() {

var app = angular.module('mybodyapp', ['ionic', 'angularMoment','LocalStorageModule']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('index', {
        url : '/',
        templateUrl : 'index.html',
        controller : 'MainController'
    });
    $stateProvider.state('list', {
        url: '/list',
        templateUrl: 'templates/list.html'
    });
    $stateProvider.state('edit', {
        url: '/edit/:noteId',
        templateUrl: 'templates/edit.html',
        controller: 'EditCtrl'
    });
    $stateProvider.state('add', {
        url: '/add',
        templateUrl: 'templates/edit.html',
        controller: 'AddCtrl'
    });
    $stateProvider.state('notes', {
        url: '/notes',
        templateUrl: 'templates/notes.html'
    });
    $stateProvider.state('posts', {
        url: '/posts',
        templateUrl: 'templates/posts.html',
        controller: 'PostsCtrl'
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
});

// ...
```

I am able to grab data from Reddit through a controller, but not data from Wordpress.  I found a good demo template but cannot figure out how to 'rewrite' the beginning of the JS controller.  I removed the top of the original `angular.module('starter.controllers', [])` and put `angular.module('mybodyapp')`  followed by:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.url = 'http://scottbolinger.com/wp-json/wp/v2/';
})
.controller('PostsCtrl', function( $scope, $http, DataLoader, $timeout, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $rootScope ) {
    console.log('PostsCtrl');

    $scope.loadPosts = function() {
        DataLoader.get( $rootScope.url + 'posts' ).then(function(response) {
            $scope.posts = response.data;
            console.log( response.data );
        }, function(response) {
            console.log('error', response);
        });
    }

    // Load posts on page load
    $scope.loadPosts();

    paged = 2;
    $scope.moreItems = true;

    // Load more (infinite scroll)
    $scope.loadMore = function() {
        if( !$scope.moreItems ) {
            return;
        }

        var pg = paged++;

        $timeout(function() {
            DataLoader.get( $rootScope.url + 'posts' + '?page=' + pg ).then(function(response) {
                angular.forEach( response.data, function( value, key ) {
                    $scope.posts.push(value);
                });

                if( response.data.length <= 0 ) {
                    $scope.moreItems = false;
                }
            }, function(response) {
                $scope.moreItems = false;
                console.log('error');
            });

            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.resize');
        }, 1000);
    }

    $scope.moreDataExists = function() {
        return $scope.moreItems;
    }

    // Pull to refresh
    $scope.doRefresh = function() {
        console.log('Refreshing!');

        $timeout( function() {
            $scope.loadPosts();

            //Stop the ion-refresher from spinning
            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
        }, 1000);
    };
})
.controller('PostCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams,     DataLoader,    $ionicLoading, $rootScope, $sce ) {
    $ionicLoading.show({
        noBackdrop: true
    });

    var singlePostApi = $rootScope.url + 'posts/' +    $stateParams.postId;

    DataLoader.get( singlePostApi ).then(function(response) {
        $scope.post = response.data;
        // Don't strip post html
        $scope.content =    $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data.content.rendered);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    }, function(response) {
        console.log('error', response);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The name in your `ng-app` directive must match your module name. The name in your `ng-controller` directive must match your controller name.

For more information on the `ng-app` directive see the [AngularJS ng-app API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp).

For the `ng-controller` directive, [AngularJS ng-controller API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)

**UPDATE**

The demo you grabbed has three controllers. You need to make them methods of `angular.module`

```
angular.module('mybodyapp').controller('AppCtrl',... 

angular.module('mybodyapp').controller('PostsCtrl', function( $sc

angular.module("mybodyapp").controller('PostCtrl', function($scope
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post my changed version.  So in my app.js, I have:

    (function() {

    var app = angular.module('myreddit', ['ionic',     'angularMoment','LocalStorageModule']);

Followed by some stateproviders.

Comment: Then in my Wordpress Controller (WPCtrl.js), I have at the beginning:

angular.module('myreddit') 

.controller('WordCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $rootScope) {

  $rootScope.url = 'http://scottbolinger.com/wp-json/wp/v2/';

})

Comment: @MarkB to edit your question, use the `edit` link. It is at the bottom your question between the `share` and `flag`

Comment: There we go.  Sorry about that